# incrementing position when clicked an item in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a multiple div when i click an item from the list, and i want to make it's position incremented from its position before, the div should have a fixed positioning, here's the example output that i want to achieve:[image]

here's my css:

```
.message_chat
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    background:black;
    right:0px;
    bottom:5px;
}
```

here's my jquery:

```
right = 50;
$('.chat_div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var pop_up = '<div class = "message_chat" id = "'+id+'"></div>';
    right+=50;
    $('#'+id).css('right',right+'px');
    $('.chatBoxHolder').append(pop_up); 
});
```

here's the code that i tried in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iloveprogramming12/kf0b6bh8/2/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: sure, give me a minute.

Comment: And your question is .... ... ... ..?

Comment: user3558931 - the div doesn't adjust it's position, I think there's something wrong with my jquery code, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var right = 50;
  $('.chat_div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $popup = $this.data('message-chat');
    //if a popup is there for this friend don't create it again
    if (!$popup) {
      var $popup = $('<div class = "message_chat" id = "chat-' + this.id + '"></div>').css('right', right + 'px').appendTo('.chatBoxHolder');
      $this.data('message-chat', $popup)
      right += 150;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.message_chat {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="1">Friend 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="2">Friend 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="3">Friend 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="chatBoxHolder"></div>
```

Comment: It works! thank you sir!! It took most of my time thinking how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using the same ID on the links as you are on the chat boxes so if you just append something like "-chat" to the new divs, that will fix the issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/kf0b6bh8/4/

```
 var id = $(this).attr('id'+'-chat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test below code , the problem with above one is you were getting id with `var id = $(this).attr('id');` than the same you were assigning to `var pop_up = '<div class = "message_chat" id = "'+id+'"></div>';` and applying styles to it with `$('#'+id).css('right',right+'px');`, so these were getting applied to these

```
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="1">Friend 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="2">Friend 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="3">Friend 3</a></li>
```

PFB code it will work for single click on each anchor,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.message_chat
        {
            width:20%;
            height:300px;
            //position:fixed;
            background:black;
            //right:0px;
            //bottom:5px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="1">Friend 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="2">Friend 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_div" id="3">Friend 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="chatBoxHolder"></div>
<script>
    right=350;
$('.chat_div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#message_chat'+id).length==0){
    var pop_up = '<div class = "message_chat" id = "message_chat'+id+'"></div>';
    if($('.chatBoxHolder').children().length== 0){
    right=0;
    }
    else {
     right=350 *$('.chatBoxHolder').children().length;
    }
    $('.chatBoxHolder').append(pop_up);
        $('#message_chat'+id).css('position','fixed');
    $('#message_chat'+id).css('right',right+'px');
    $('#message_chat'+id).css('bottom','0px');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```